# How to change login screen to allow login to active directory domain in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: ubuntu, login, authentication, active-directory, prompt

So, I have an Ubuntu 12.10 machine that has been joined to an active directory domain.   However, when the machine turns on and I am presented with a login screen, I cant just type DOMAIN\user.   All I can do is select my name (which I entered when I first setup this install) and enter my local password.   How do I modifiy the login screen so I cant actually enter my DOMAIN\user and AD password to authenticate?

FYI I used LikeWise-Open to authenticate to the windows domain if that matters.

Let me know if you need any further info.

Update: I have added a screenshot of my login screen after running the command that was suggested..

[image]

Comment: What version of LikeWise-Open?

Comment: 6.1.0.406-0ubuntu6

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it answers your question or solves your problem.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get into the `asci-console`.

From there just login with your active-directory username and according password. After you logged in successfully, logout again (with the command: `logout`) and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to close the console.

The Active-Directory User should now appear...don't ask me why.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command from Terminal.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'
```

Comment: Hmm, no dice.   Now, what is this lightdm ting?   Do I need to have this installed first?   Any other changes needed in order to make this work.   I was able to run the command but when I restarted my machine I am left with the same exact prompt that I had before...